# How to print as PDF all pages in HTML?

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I have this [html/JS](https://jsfiddle.net/06oxhyrb/) code that generates N tables based on user input. I'm trying to separate the content in pages of "A4" size and with no more that 6 tables within each page in order to give the option to print as PDF.

I'm using the built-in JS function `window.print()`. The issue is that when the browser opens up the printing preview window, only detects 2 pages and only first page content appears correct, the rest appears empty.

You can try for example to generate 24 tables (that would be 4 pages) and when click on print, only 2 pages are detected.

Basically I'm using this to convert as PDF the content generated by the other 2 JS codes.

```
<button onclick="printPDF()">Print PDF</button>

    function printPDF() {
        window.print();
    }
```

How to fix this, in order to print all pages? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the `hidden` page overspill
so simply remove that such that all contents are eligible for printing. Note you may want to move `hidden` to just the button at print time.

And the 2nd is you may need a `page-break-after: always;`
when the table container blocks reach 6 to a page limit, so try add that in. Note even with all 6 it will not add a blank page unless the table is too close to the edge so it overspills, hence the 7th (13th ... etc.) triggers the page break.

**Later Edit** I seems that an auto page-break is added in the fiddle so may not be needed? However I also had issues with FireFox assessment of page height so for my MS printing had to reduce between 3-6mm to not trigger an extra page!

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/61qshzvc/

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions. Not sure why, but when I go to your link, happens the same. Only detects 2 pages and the second one is empty. I've tried in Chrome and Brave browsers.

Comment: Thanks again. This time it already detects all the pages, although it is creating an extra one that is almost empty, because it contains one or two rows from the previous tables. It seems that it is gradually moving a few pixels on each page and that is why there are some that appear cut off

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it works better the code than my original one